# Google Sheets Lunch Break Comparing Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, time, break

Please can some one help
So I have a list of people with their 3 breaks in

Name | First Break | Lunch | Last Break

John | 8:00        | 13:00 | 17:00

Peter| 8:15        | 13:45 | 17:15

Jane | 8:30        | 13:15 | 17:30

Frank| 8:45        | 13:00 | 17:45

Paul | 9:00        | 15:30 | 18:00

I am looking to get a result of "John, Jane, Frank, YOUR breaks are to close together" when any of the "Lunches" are overlapping by 15 mins or more up to the 30 mins of their break

i can get a result of

[My Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zoV2.png)

with =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(A1:C,A1:C8)>1,A1:A8,))

with but I can not for the life of me work out how to get this solved I will be so thankful for any help

**UPDATE**
So I now have it where I can get the list of names where the Breaks match with the formula

=JOIN(", ",Filter(A2:A9,COUNTIF(C2:C9,C2:C9)>1))

[With the list of people](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxTGb.png)

So now i just need it if the Lunch times are =to or over lap by > 15 mins, and split this list into their groups

Comment: Each person looks like the have two break times... why three columns? Which column is which?

Comment: yea so each person gets 3 breaks a day first and last is 15 mins the Lunch is the one i am worried about as i can not have people of at the same time for 30 mins at a time